# ajax delete div from view on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax image uploader that I am currently trying to do a delete link for, I have the delete script working, but on success I want it to also remove the `div` and replace with "Image Deleted" text, but I am a little confused on how to remove a `div` where the `id` will always be different (set from a var).

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.trash',function(){
        var image_id= $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/includes/delete_image.php',
            data:{'image_id':image_id},
            success: function(data){
                 if(data=="YES"){
                   $('#image_id').remove()
                 }else{
                        alert("can't delete the row")
                 }
             }

            });
        });
});
```

That's the code, so on `data=="YES"` I want this:

```
<div id="image_id">
   <img src=\"/uploads/articles/article_images/image_name" class='imgList'><br />
BBCode: <input type="text" class="form-control" value="[img]http://www.prxa.info/uploads/articles/article_images/{$image_name}[/img]\" /><br />";
    <a href="#" id="image_id" class="trash">Delete Image</a>
</div>
```

To be deleted, where `"image_id"` will be a number set as `"image_id"` in the ajax code, any pointers? I am doing it horribly wrong right now heh.

"image_id" is different everytime of course.

Comment: Can we see some HTML? I'll try and write an answer anyway

Comment: Sorry it was there but the code tag messed up, fixed it now.

Comment: can you please your html code? so its easy to give an answer of your question.

Comment: Look up ^ I put it in properly ;)

Comment: may I know what about `{$image_id}` ..

Comment: {$image_id} is replaced by my php to be the image id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have more than 1 element with the same id, so to get the div you could try:

```
$("div[id='image_id']").remove();
```

Comment: That just does nothing.

Comment: then the HTML in your question is wrong ^^. `<div id="image_id">`

Comment: So as "image_id" isn't fixed, the very bottom line of my post = "image_id" is different everytime of course.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to change this:

```
$('#image_id').remove();
```

to this:

```
$('#'+image_id).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you have the image_id as a variable. So you should be able to use in your success callback.

```
$('#'+image_id).html('image was deleted successfully...');
```

You can give the id's different prefixes like

```
'div_' + image_id and 'img_' + image_id
```

Comment: Sadly this does nothing. I am guessing as both the div and link have the same id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML div is repeating, you won't want them to all have the same id. Change this to a class of image, or something else meaningful to your css.

You do this two ways. Either set a data attribute on the div, or use the parent jquery function to get the parent div of the link you clicked.

Setting the data attribute is probably considered better practice. Add the attribute data-image-id, and then you can select the div based on that attribute's value, and then remove it.

```
<div data-image-id="[your image id]">
```

Then you can then select the div based on the attribute as explained in the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: The id will be different everytime, it's an id of the image.

Comment: Ah ok. In which case, I suggest you change the id to something like "image-[number]" rather than just the id, allowing you to use numbers elsewhere

Comment: Using the same id for the div and the link could cause problems, which is why I suggest you use a data attribute =]

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to show that so I can see?

Comment: In addition to using the data attribute for the div, I would also use it for the anchor tag, and just change the attribute you get the id from to match the new name

Answer (score 0):

use this

`$("#"+image_id).remove();`

instead of

`$('#image_id').remove();`